# Wanting a datediff formula to get the difference in seconds between each trasntype

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Was hoping to get some insight into what I should include in a Datediff formula to calculate the difference in time between columns and rows. Using the "timestamp" column as the date, and the "transtype" column as the modifier. So something along the lines of "timestamp (TR) - Timestamp (FIN)". I've attached a screenshot for what the data looks like.

I'm essentially trying to find a formula that calculates the time between each "transaction" or "transtype", per "incident" or "inci_id".

Thank you for your time and assistance.

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toa7T.png)

Comment: Could you tag the database you are using ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to share files from the database I am using, sorry about that.

Comment: You mean the datediff() function with the first parameter as "s"?